# Изображение в EditText как в vk

Tags: android, вконтакте, android-edittext, bitmap

Как внутрь EditText загрузить изображение? Нужно так, как в приложении vk, пример смотрите на скриншоте ниже. Заранее спасибо.

[image: лалала]

Comment: cпасибо, что уменьшили картинку) как вы это делаете? Чтобы я сразу сам делал, а то я не находил, а на большие самому неприятно смотреть))

Comment: Просто добавьте соответствующую буквы в конец адреса изображения, но перед точкой. Я обычно добавляю `m`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не картинка в EditText. Это картинка под ним. Такие вещи можно увидеть, включив "показывать границы макета" В настройках разработчика на девайсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, теперь вопрос, нужно ли будет производить какие-либо доп.манипуляции, чтобы изображение было на переднем плане?

Comment: @Maxgmer, не очень понял вопрос. Имеете в виду чтоб оно под клавиатуру не уходило?..

Comment: чтобы оно не было под белым полотном EditText'а. Или оно сразу будет видно? И как узнать, в каком месте заканчивается текст, чтобы рассчитать положение картинки?

Comment: Если вы используете LinearLayout вертикальный то EditText никогда не перекроет картинку ниже если вы ему ещё и maxHeight назначите или maxLines